# Super Micro hangs in BIOS enumerating devices

Tags: bios, supermicro

I've got a Super Micro X8DTT-H server. I've been wrestling with various issues trying to get the server installed with CentOS 6. At one point I had the server booted from the IPMI-attached DVD drive. I wanted to reboot the server but I got an error that the system could not be rebooted. So, I reset the system via IMPI. Now, whenever it comes up it hangs, trying to enumerating the drives.

[image]

I've looked through the manual for the motherboard/BIOS and I've tried DEL and a variety of function keys via the IPMI soft keyboard. No luck.

Short of driving to the data center and pulling the drive (or disconnecting it) is there a way to get the BIOS to ignore that hard drive check and just boot from the CD again?

Comment: It says there are two connected SATA devices, but only listed one. So your problem is _probably_ with the other device, and you'll almost certainly have to physically visit the hardware.

Comment: @MichaelHampton You should write that as an answer :) (you can delete my comment if you do ;p)

Answer (score 2):

Your second hard drive is defective and is blocking the POST. You will need to physically unplug the drive and it should boot normally.